# Avoiding a repeated call to same API in AngularJS from 2 controllers during page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a single page app built using AngularJS. When the page first loads,  there are two controllers that execute and these are 'Controller1' and 'Controller2'.

- Each of them needs to make a call to the same WebAPI in order to meet its logic requirements.
- Also, 'Controller1' code executes first, but due to the async nature of the code, 'Conroller2' code starts to execute before the Controller1 call to WebAPI has returned successfully.

**Question**: How can I make sure that only Controller1 makes the call to WebAPI, so that Controller2 simply uses the call in Controller1 rather than making a repeated call?

**Controller1**

```
dashboardDataService.getAllDashboards().then(onDashboardListReceived)
```

**Controller2**

```
dashboardDataService.getAllDashboards().then(onDashboardListReceived)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.service('dashboardDataService', function($http){
    var dashboardDataServiceScope = this;

    var allDashboardsPromise = false;

    dashboardDataServiceScope.getAllDashboards = function(){
        if(!allDashboardsPromise){
            allDashboardsPromise = $http.post(...);
        }
        return allDashboardsPromise;
    };
});
```

What this will do will create a promise the first time, and then every time something else calls it will just return the same promise. So you can have multiple hooked into one.

Comment: Shouldn't  ' return allDashboardsDeferred.promise' be just ' return allDashboardsDeferred', since allDashboardsDeferred becomes a promise when used with $http.post(...).then(...)?

Comment: You're right, I had initially wired it up with $q :)